# subprocess.CalledProcessError when attempting to install torchac for PyTorch 1.2

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, subprocess

I am trying to install `torchac` for Python 3.6 and PyTorch 1.2, but got this error:

```
Using /home/neetu/.cache/torch_extensions as PyTorch extensions root...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "savecode//main.py", line 8, in
from net import *
File "/mnt/c/users/2004062.local/desktop/python/savecode/DVC/examples/example/savecode/net.py", line 16, in
import torchac
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchac/init.py", line 2, in
from torchac.torchac import encode_float_cdf
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchac/torchac.py", line 16, in
verbose=True)
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1092, in load
keep_intermediates=keep_intermediates)
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1303, in _jit_compile
is_standalone=is_standalone)
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1379, in _write_ninja_file_and_build_library
check_compiler_abi_compatibility(compiler)
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 283, in check_compiler_abi_compatibility
if not check_compiler_ok_for_platform(compiler):
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 243, in check_compiler_ok_for_platform
which = subprocess.check_output(['which', compiler], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output
**kwargs).stdout
File "/home/neetu/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 438, in run
output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['which', 'c++']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like `c++` is a requirement but is not found.

Comment: If it's [this `torchac`](https://github.com/fab-jul/torchac), there is no version for Python 3.6 and PyTorch 1.2. Consider making a new environment with at least Python 3.8 and PyTorch 1.5-1.7.

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential   - Its works for me.